# Was the hotel shut down in the last episode of "Fawlty Towers"?

Tags: analysis, fawlty-towers

Throughout the series, it was implied that the titular "Fawlty Towers" hotel had been of poor quality / reputation. Customers, especially the Upper-class, had been disgusted at the quality of service that the hotel provides. There has been chaos, even fatal disasters. In the episode "the Hotel Inspectors", Mr. Fawlty's expressed fear in getting the hotel shut down, as he was expecting inspectors that review and rate hotels, whose dissatisfaction would lead to the downfall of this hotel.

Could this fear have finally come to life in the last episode, when the Inspector found a rat in the box of biscuits? The inspector gravely threatened the hotel's continuation, even though his complaints were implied to be comical nit-picks. So it's not very surprising that a plague-ridden rat in a box of biscuits would easily get him on his nerves.

There was never another episode, so could that have been the end of Fawlty Towers literally? John Cleese and Connie Booth never wanted to continue the series, due to how strenuous the writing process is. Did the ex-couple cleverly plan this very comical ending, whilst covering up the dark and disheartening truth behind it?